# Use Intel ASM syntax when compiling with TinyCC

Tags: c, assembly, tcc

When compiling a project with Tiny C Compiler, is it possible to use Intel assembly syntax in inline assembly blocks?

Comment: Btw - just wondering why you're using TCC..

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not.

TCC only supports AT&T syntax